# parsing gcov data without external libraries

Tags: c, unit-testing, code-coverage, gcov

I want to get an output like this:
[image: a busy cat]

I know I can get these results by using lcov, but I'm not allowed to use an external libraries. Is there some other way I can get this information easily (besides parsing manually the result of invoking gcov)?

In addition, I need it to work on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Why don't you try Excel?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie , the graphic aren't really matter, I'm interested mainly in the numbers here. I don't know an easy way to get them

Comment: You can use Excel too to do counting and tabluar display. Visual Basic is a good tool for that.